# Windows Task Manager: Switch to window associated with process

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

I have multiple instances of the same program running. Say I notice in the process tab that one of the instances is using 22GB of RAM. How can identify which of the instances this is, i.e. switch to the associated window? All I see is the option to kill the process, but I'd rather investigate the massive RAM use in a "non-destructive" way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download something far more powerful called [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from SysInternals/Microsoft, right-click the instance, open the **Window** sub-menu and click on **Bring to Front**.

You can also make Process Explorer replace Task Manager:

[image: 1]

Comment: Replacing the Task Manger worked once I had followed [these instructions](http://forum.sysinternals.com/win7-64bit-replace-task-manager_topic22527.html) that let me figure out why the system wasn't finding the process explorer. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: anyone knows, why the window menu could be greyed out (deactivated)? I tried it on a Winword-Application that was started in background.

Comment: Yeah, multiple Firefox windows are open, one of which is hogging the CPU, but when I right-click on that window in Process Explorer, the Window option is grayed out.